# Why doesn't the following (perfectly valid) C code show the contents of a file in Objective-C?

Tags: c, objective-c, system-calls

Here's a very basic C snippet to open and read a file:

```
  int fd = open("test.txt",O_RDONLY);
  char buf[128];
  int reader = read(fd,buf,128);
  int i;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(buf);i++)
    {
        printf("%i: I read: %c", i, (int)buf[i]);
    }
```

I'm also including these standard headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
```

This code will work fine in C, and since Objective-C is a superset of C I expected it to work fine in Obj-C as well. But instead I'm getting all garbage data, such as:

```
0: I read: –
1: I read: *
2: I read: :
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `open` call is probably failing.  Try specifying the full path to the file, and employ some error checking.

Comment: Brilliant. I can't believe it was this easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use strlen on the output buffer from read() - it isn't null-terminated.

Comment: Fair enough...but I don't think this is the reason the code is failing.

Answer (score 1):

First, having the strlen() call in your for statement is a **very** bad practice... unless the compiler optimizes it out, your loop will run in Order N**2 time.

Second, how do you know the buffer is zero-terminated? You're making an assumption here that may not be valid. Since you know the size of the buffer (128), you should be using a constant, e.g., BUFSIZE and the conditional in the loop should be 'i < BUFSIZE'.

Third, you are casting the character value stored in buf[i] to an int, and then printing it as a char. Evidently Objective-C doesn't do this in the same way that your desktop C compiler does, and this is weakly defined in the language anyway. It would be better to just reference buf[i] without casting it to an int. I'm sure that this is where your problem is.

Comment: Your first two points are valid, but the cast to `int` is perfectly fine.  For variadic functions like printf, the extra arguments undergo promotion, whereby `char`s are promoted to `int`s implicitly (among other promotions).  Casting it to `int` just makes the promotion explicit instead of implicit.  It's better to remove it, but it will still function perfectly fine with the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the responses so far, and adding my own observations:

You should check the return value from `open()` and `read()`.  If they fail, you're going to blindly continue on and print garbage.

`read()` returns the number of characters read, or -1 in case of error.  It does NOT null-terminate its buffer, so using `strlen()` to find the amount of data read is wrong.

You shouldn't put a call to `strlen()` in the loop test condition, since you'll be re-evaluating it each iteration.

The casting of `buf[i]` to `int` in the `printf` statement is unnecessary.  The extra arguments to variadic functions such as `printf` (that is, all of the arguments that make up the `...`) undergo default argument promotion as follows:

- `char`s, `short`s, and their unsigned counterparts are promoted to `int`s
- `float`s are promoted to `double`s

Without a cast, `buf[i]` would get implicitly promoted to an `int` anyways, so adding the cast, while correct, makes the code more confusing to anyone reading it.

So, your code should look like this:

```
int fd = open("test.txt",O_RDONLY);
if(fd < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "open failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return;
}
char buf[128];
// It's better to use sizeof(buf) here, so we don't have to change it in case we
// change the size of buf.  -1 to leave space for the null terminator
int reader = read(fd,buf,sizeof(buf)-1);
if(reader < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "read failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    close(fd);
    return;
}
buf[reader] = 0;  // add null terminator for safety
int i;
for (i=0; i < reader; i++)
{
    printf("%i: I read: %c", i, buf[i]);
}
```